# Trying to change stylesheet url

Tags: .htaccess

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /application/

RewriteRule (.*)/css/(.*).css www/$1/css/$2.css

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1
```

So my end goal here is to have

```
http://localhost/application/guestbook/css/style.css
```

forwarded to

```
/application/www/guestbook/css/style.css
```

It's almost working, yet when im dumping $_GET i can see that the url he's looking for is

```
www/www/guestbook/css/style.css
```

Can someone tell me why its having 2times www/ ? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Your first group is grabbing the entire beginning of the url, i.e. `www/directory` and not just `directory`. A quick fix would be changing your rewrite rule to `/(.*?)/css/(.*).css`. The `?` after the `.*` tells it to be ungreedy, that is, to match as little as possible.

Comment: With RewriteRule /(.?)/css/(.*).css www/$1/css/$2.css the url that its going to is not changing e.g. with the / in front of it it does not work. Using RewriteRule (.?)/css/(.*).css www/$1/css/$2.css results in this: www/k/css/style.css/css/style.css so it took just the last letter of guestbook. Any idea?

Comment: The grouping is not `(.?)`, it needs to be `(.*?)`. The first will indeed only match the last letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

**UPDATED**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/(\w+/\w+/\w+\.css)$
RewriteRule .* application/www/%1 [L]
```

Will redirect this:

`http://localhost/application/anything1/anything2/anything3.css`  to

`http://localhost/application/www/anything1/anything2/anything3.css`

Comment: Hey, I've tryed this, but it does not work (404 error) :( Could there just be something wrong with my apache?

Comment: You are right. There was an error in my answer. I modified it. If still there is an error, please copy-paste in a comment the URL entered in the browser address bar along with the URL displayed in the message error

Comment: http://localhost/application/guestbook/css/style.css is the one im going to and the error is a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: OK. ¿Is there this `http://localhost/www/application/guestbook/css/style.css` in your directory structure? Because that is the path you want in your question an the one the rewrite rule is mapping to.

Comment: No I want it to go to http://localhost/application/www/guestbook/css/style.css because without any rewriterules, thats exactly where the file is located yes

Edit to make it a little bit more clear, this line DOES work:
RewriteRule (.*)/css/(.*).css www/guestbook/css/$2.css

But I want guestbook to be dynamic

Comment: It worked! For some reason I added RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f before the rewriterule line and now suddenly it workes. ...

Comment: Anyway, I will correct the path in the rule. `www` is above `application` and it should be below. I will update the answer in some minutes.